# How to use fill inside the tidyverse complete function to fill all dataframe columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I generate the following test dataframe output when running the code below, for original `data` dataframe and by running the function `state_inflow`:

```
> test
   Previous_State 1 2 3
1:             X0 2 0 0
2:             X1 0 0 0
3:             X2 0 0 1

    library(data.table)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    data <- 
      data.frame(
        ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
        Period_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
        Period_2 = c("2020-01","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04","2020-05","2020-06","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04"),
        Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
        State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X3")
      )
    
    state_inflow <- function(mydat, target_state, period_col_name, fct) {
      dcast(
        setDT(mydat)[, Previous_State := factor(shift(State, fill = target_state)), by = ID][
          , period_factor := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = period_col_name],
        Previous_State ~ period_factor, fct, 
        value.var = "Values", subset = .(State == target_state), drop = FALSE
      ) 
    }
    
    test <- state_inflow(data, "X0", "Period_1", length)
```

I'm adding a row to the dataframe to include those "state" combinations that never touch the `target_state` category (see ID 3 in the `data` dataframe; across periods it never touches the target state of x0 and is therefore excluded from the original `test` output shown above), and populating all of those columns added for that new row with 0's. I am now doing this as follows:

```
test %>%
  complete(Previous_State = unique(data$State)) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

which gives me correct output of:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Previous_State   `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr>          <int> <int> <int>
1 X0                 2     0     0
2 X1                 0     0     0
3 X2                 0     0     1
4 X3                 0     0     0
```

See how row 4, "X3", was added with all 0's? That's correct output.

I'm trying to learn how to use `complete(... ,fill = ...)`. How would I accomplish what I did above, but by instead using `fill = ...` inside the `complete(...)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fill` argument of `complete` expects a list to set the value for each individual column. By default, this is `NA` for all columns. You can change this by setting the desired filling value for each column separately:

```
test %>%
  complete(Previous_State = unique(data$State),
    fill = list(`1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  Previous_State   `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 X0                 2     0     0
#2 X1                 0     0     0
#3 X2                 0     0     1
#4 X3                 0     0     0
```

Since your question is about the tidyverse: A tidy data frame is normalized so that you usually have only one column for each property. This makes the completing much easier to archive the same result:

```
test %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("^[0-9]+$")) %>%
  complete(Previous_State = unique(data$State), name,
    fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Comment: Hi danlooo, thanks for the help! If it were you, working with a dataframe of 3 million + rows (for which data.table is working great and fast), would you use the complete(...(fill = ...)) solution you drafted? Or my simple method shown in OP of adding the row using complete(...) (with no fill) and then changing all NA to 0 using replace(is.na(.), 0)?

Comment: Do you need to run the code every hour for the next years? If not, it does not matter. Make it work, then make it right and lastly, make it fast. Note that, unlike tidyverse, data.table modifies your input data making it very hard hard to reproduce correct results.